# Creating a custom sys.stdout class?

Tags: python, stdout

What I'm trying to do is simply have the output of some terminal commands print out to a wx.TextCtrl widget.  I figured the easiest way to accomplish this is to create a custom stdout class and overload the write function to that of the widget.

stdout class:

```
class StdOut(sys.stdout):
    def __init__(self,txtctrl):
        sys.stdout.__init__(self)
        self.txtctrl = txtctrl

    def write(self,string):
        self.txtctrl.write(string)
```

And then I would do something such as:

```
sys.stdout = StdOut(createdTxtCtrl)    
subprocess.Popen('echo "Hello World!"',stdout=sys.stdout,shell=True)
```

What results is the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mainwindow.py", line 12, in <module>
from systemconsole import SystemConsole
File "systemconsole.py", line 4, in <module>
class StdOut(sys.stdout):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
file() argument 2 must be string, not tuple
```

Any ideas to fix this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`sys.stdout` is **not** a `class`, it's an **instance** (of type `file`).

So, just do:

```
class StdOut(object):
    def __init__(self,txtctrl):
        self.txtctrl = txtctrl
    def write(self,string):
        self.txtctrl.write(string)

sys.stdout = StdOut(the_text_ctrl)
```

No need to inherit from `file`, just make a simple file-like object like this!  *Duck typing* is your friend...

(Note that in Python, like most other OO languages but differently from Javascript, you only ever inherit from classes AKA types, **never** from *instances* of classes/types;-).

Comment: I tried this, and it resulted in:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blade_gui.py", line 179, in OnNew
    subprocess.Popen('echo "Hello World!"',stdout=sys.stdout,shell=True)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 614, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 734, in _get_handles
    c2pwrite = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(stdout.fileno())
AttributeError: 'StdOut' object has no attribute 'fileno'

Comment: `subprocess` can execute programs written in any language (not just Python!) and so needs a "real OS-level file" (i.e., one with a FD, also known as fileno) -- no way to pass anything as the `stdout=` of `subprocess.Popen` except a real OS-level file (including, fortunately, `subprocess.PIPE`, which lets your parent process receive the child process's output -- however, buffering in the child process typically means this isn't what you want, so I always suggest using `pexpect` or `wexpect` instead).

Comment: you need more than just `write`, you also need `flush`, maybe some others depending on how it will be used.

Comment: @Duck - I wrote an example that should handle many more cases. Please see my answer. If there are any other edge cases, let me know and I'll be glad to ammend.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to implement is writing, there is no need to define a new class at all. Simply use `createdTxtCtrl` instead of `StdOut(createdTxtCtrl)`, because the former already supports the operation you need.

If all you need to do with stdout is direct some programs' output there, not direct all kinds of stuff there, don't change `sys.stdout`, just instantiate the `subprocess.Popen` with your own file-like object (`createdTxtCtrl`) instead of `sys.stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed a package to PyPi called [tiotrap](https://github.com/JavaScriptDude/tiotrap), which contains `TextIOTrap` helper class for managing TextIO Streams.

Installation:

```
python3 -m pip install tiotrap
```

Trap writes to a list, you could implement your own handler with this method as well, just substitute the lambda with a function/method call:

```py
import tiotrap
aTrappedStdout = []
_stdout_bk = sys.stdout

sys.stdout = tiotrap.TextIOTrap(write_handler=lambda s: aTrappedStdout.append(s))

print("TEST1")
print("TEST2")

sys.stdout = _stdout_bk
print(f"aTrappedStdout = {aTrappedStdout}")
# output: aTrappedStdout = ['TEST1', 'TEST2']
```

Here is a way you can use it to store the captured data:

```py
_stdout_bk = sys.stdout

tio_trap = tiotrap.TextIOTrap(store=True)

sys.stdout = tio_trap
print("TEST1")
print("TEST2")
sys.stdout = _stdout_bk

print(f"captured logs:\n{str(tio_trap)}\n~end~\n")
# output: 
# captured logs:
# TEST1
# TEST2
# ~end~
```

As a cross platform DEVNULL replacement:

```py
_stdout_bk = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = tiotrap.DEVNULL
print("THIS WILL NOT PRINT")
sys.stdout = _stdout_bk
print("THIS WILL PRINT")
```

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't `sys.stdout = StdOut(createdTxtCtrl)` create cyclical dependency?  Try not reassigning `sys.stdout` to the class derived from `sys.stdout`.