# Access/save stdout of a Python3 script from within Python

Tags: python

I've been running in circles, trying to find a way to solve this.

I run a script, which call `pytest`; which produce some output in terminal. The idea is to get this output, and put it in a variable, so I can either save it to a file, print it somewhere (like in a tkinter label object for example, if I ever plan to make the script part of a UI).

I did find about sys.stdout; but it seems that it is used TO print on screen (console in this case); which is not what I am looking for. I am trying to read what is sent to the console and printed.

The only solution so far is to do a redirect from the shell, when I call the python script; which sadly is not really an option for me, considering that I don't need the whole output of all that I do in that script, but only the output of `pytest`, so stdout and stderr.
I assume that the data is buffered somewhere and then sent out for print on screen, although I did try to use `sys.stdout` without luck.

There is a section in the pytest docs that mention capturing stdout/stderr, but either they didn't include some important details, or I am not able to understand how this works

```
def test_myoutput(capsys): # or use "capfd" for fd-level
    print("hello")
    sys.stderr.write("world\n")
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    assert captured.out == "hello\n"
    assert captured.err == "world\n"
    print("next")
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    assert captured.out == "next\n"
```

From this except, there is this object called `capsys`, which has a property called `readouterr()`, which should output errors (and I assume there is an equivalent for stdout); although capsys seems to not be part of pytest at all.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: all systems can save console output using `>` - ie. `python script.py > output.txt`

Comment: if you run program using `subprocess` then you can catch `stdout` so you catch all `print()` (which uses `sys.stdout` in background)

Comment: [Creating a custom sys.stdout class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297933/creating-a-custom-sys-stdout-class) You can assing this class to `sys.stdout` and `print()` will use it instead of sending on screen.

Comment: @furas  I am aware of that; but as mentioned in the question, I do not need the whole output of the script, since it does more than just testing; and make sense more to save only the output that you need, instead than dump everything. Also I believe that when I redirect the output, I have to wait the end of the execution to be able to access the file; which is not ideal

Comment: Also I am aware of subprocess; but won't fit my needs; since in that way the application will halt for as long as the subprocess is running; which is not ideal too. I think that the only way to go at this point is a custom stdout class; although this means that I won't get any output while the app is running.

I am amazed that there is no easy way to get the output of the script via code, so you don't need to rely on the redirection in the shell. Thanks for the suggestions!